# Cannot establish video call with WebRTC and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, socket.io, webrtc

I need to create an application for a video call using `WebRTC`. It should work as follows.

On the main page there is a button (link) to the video calling page. The route `id` is a string of random characters. Next, the client joins the room by sending a request to the server via `socket.io`. The generated `id` is also displayed on the page. This is a full-stack application based on `Node.js`, `React`, `Socket.io`, `TypeScript`, `WebRTC`. I simplified everything as much as possible to focus on `WebRTC` technology.

To make a call, we need to fill the input with another client's `id` and press the "Connect" button below. I need the user to see the video from the interlocutor’s device when establishing the connection, and vice versa (for example, as it works in *WhatsApp* video call). On each device, permission to use a microphone and camera is turned on.

For signaling purposes, I use `socket.io` on `node.js` server.
The problem is that when making a call, the video is sometimes displayed by both users, sometimes only on one device. Sometimes there is no video at both sides. In general, the application works unstable.

Here is the socket.io server code:

```
import { io } from ".";

interface Signal {
  operation: 'join' | 'offer' | 'answer' | 'ice';
  source?: string;
  target: string;
  data: any;
}

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("server", (arg: Signal) => {
    console.log(arg)
    if(arg.operation==='join') {
      socket.join(arg.target);
    }
    if(arg.operation==='offer' || arg.operation==='answer' || arg.operation==='ice') {
      console.log(arg.operation);
      io.to(arg.target).emit(arg.target, arg)
    }
  });
});
```

The main page of `React` client. When clicking on the button, we go into the room (route with a random `id`):

```
import React from "react";
import { XButton2 } from "../components/Buttons";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const makeId = (length: number): string => {
  let result = "";
  const characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  const charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
};

export default function Main() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  function create() {
    const id = makeId(4);
    navigate(`/room/${id}`);
  }

  return <XButton2 onClick={create}>Create room</XButton2>;
}
```

The room page:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import { AiOutlineLeft } from "react-icons/ai";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import RoomContainer from "../components/RoomContainer";

export default function Room() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <IconButton
        sx={{ mb: 3, fontSize: "35px", border: "1px solid #ddd" }}
        onClick={() => navigate("/")}
      >
        <AiOutlineLeft />
      </IconButton>
      {id ? <RoomContainer id={id} /> : null}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

The connection component with all WebRTC logic and socket.io client signals:

```
import React, {
  ChangeEvent,
  Fragment,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardHeader,
  Snackbar,
  Stack,
  TextField,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { XButton1 } from "./Buttons";
import { rtcConfig } from "../../rtcConfig";

interface Signal {
  operation: "join" | "offer" | "answer" | "ice";
  source?: string;
  target: string;
  data?: any;
}

const VITE_SOCK_API = import.meta.env.VITE_SOCK_API;

const socket = io(VITE_SOCK_API);

const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(rtcConfig);

export default function RoomContainer({ id }: { id: string }) {
  const remoteRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");

  async function call() {
    const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    const mySignal: Signal = {
      operation: "offer",
      source: id,
      target: value,
      data: offer,
    };
    socket.emit("server", mySignal);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // VIDEO!!!
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true,
      })
      .then((stream) => {
        // Join
        const mySignal: Signal = { operation: "join", target: id };
        socket.emit("server", mySignal);

        stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
          peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream);
        });

        // Incoming sockets
        socket.on(id, async (arg: Signal) => {
          // Incoming offer
          if (arg.operation === "offer" && arg.source) {
            peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
              new RTCSessionDescription(arg.data)
            );
            const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
            await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
            const mySignal: Signal = {
              operation: "answer",
              source: id,
              target: arg.source,
              data: answer,
            };
            socket.emit("server", mySignal);
          }
          // Recieve an answer
          if (arg.operation === "answer") {
            const remoteDesc = new RTCSessionDescription(arg.data);
            await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteDesc);
          }
          // Ice candidate
          if (arg.operation === "ice") {
            try {
              const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(arg.data); // ??????
              await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
            } catch (e) {
              console.error("Error adding received ice candidate", e);
            }
          }
        });
      });
  }, []);

  peerConnection.addEventListener("track", async (event) => {
    const [remoteStream] = event.streams;
    if (remoteRef.current) remoteRef.current.srcObject = remoteStream;
  });

  // Listen for local ICE candidates on the local RTCPeerConnection
  peerConnection.addEventListener("icecandidate", (event) => {
    console.log(event.candidate);
    if (event.candidate) {
      const mySignal: Signal = {
        operation: "ice",
        source: id,
        target: value,
        data: event.candidate,
      };
      socket.emit("server", mySignal);
    }
  });

  // Listen for connectionstatechange on the local RTCPeerConnection
  peerConnection.addEventListener("connectionstatechange", (event) => {
    if (peerConnection.connectionState === "connected") {
      setMessage("Peers connected!");
    }
  });

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Card>
        <CardHeader
          title="Connect and open media channel"
          sx={{ borderBottom: "1px solid #ddd" }}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Stack spacing={2}>
            <Typography
              variant="h5"
              sx={{
                cursor: "pointer",
                border: "1px solid #ddd",
                borderRadius: "5px",
                p: 2,
              }}
              onClick={() => {
                if (id) {
                  navigator.clipboard.writeText(id);
                  setMessage("Copied");
                }
              }}
            >
              {id}
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              label="Connect other client"
              variant="outlined"
              value={value}
              onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                setValue(e.target.value)
              }
            />
            <XButton1
              onClick={async () => {
                // offer
                if (id && value) call();
              }}
            >
              Connect
            </XButton1>
            <Box sx={{ width: "100%", pb: "65%", position: "relative", border: '1px solid #ddd' }}>
              <video
                ref={remoteRef}
                autoPlay
                playsInline
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  left: 0,
                  top: 0,
                  width: "100%",
                  height: "100%",
                }}
              />
            </Box>
          </Stack>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
      <Snackbar
        open={Boolean(message.length)}
        autoHideDuration={3000}
        onClose={() => setMessage("")}
        message={message}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

I also noticed that during the connection, the "ice candidates" recieving is triggered many times (I included the `console.log` listener inside it, it is shown at the last code section).
The full code is also available at this github repository:

https://github.com/narzantaria/webrtc-app

Please tell me what needs to be fixed or added for proper video connection.
Thanks for attention!